# Nuxt event listener triggers only once after data transform

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I have a Vue component that lists some items. Globally, when a certain event occurs, I want to transform this list (e.g. using splice) rather than re-pulling the entire list data.

**PROBLEM:** The Nuxt listener does trigger, but only ONCE. As a test, if I disable the splice operation within, the problem disappears: it always triggers.

I've been trialling all kinds of things for days and I'm lost! Any ideas?

Abstracted/redacted code below:

```
<script>

export default {

    data() {
        return {
            fullPosts: []
        }
    },


    mounted() {

        console.log("MYCOMP.VUE fetch()")
        this.getFullPosts()

        this.$nuxt.$on('myGlobalEvent', (payload) => {

            // THE BELOW LOGIC ONLY WORKS ON FIRST TRIGGER of this listener.
            // If I comment out the splice line further down, this logic ALWAYS runs.

            // This log never occurs on subsequent triggers!
            console.log("MYCOMP.VUE listener myGlobalEvent")

            let index = this.fullPosts.findIndex( i => i.id === payload.post_id)
            if (index != -1) {
                console.log("MYCOMP.VUE doing splice")
                let newFullPosts = this.fullPosts

                // I need this line, but it causes the 'myGlobalEvent' listener to not-work on subsequent triggers.
                // Something about manipulating this.fullPosts in this component instance is disrupting the listener?
                newFullPosts.splice(index, 1)

                // As another test, if I were to use alternative logic to do the same thing, the trigger issue exists.
                //let {[index]: _, ...x} = this.fullPosts
                //let newFullPosts = Object.values(x)

                this.fullPosts = newFullPosts
            }

            console.log("MYCOMP.VUE listener myGlobalEvent")

        })
    },

    methods: {

        getFullPosts() {
            this.$axios.get("api/mything")
            .then(response => {
                this.fullPosts = response.data
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error("ERROR: %O", error)
            })
        }

    }

}
</script>
```

Comment: I'm not sure if it's related but `splice` mutates the original array. Maybe try with `slice` or something else?

Comment: I did try slice; no change. Also, as a test I implemented my own eventbus (as I've done in other Vue apps) and everything works fine! So something about this context and Nuxt's built-in event bus, is not working. I'll try to narrow it down and post about this.

Comment: Why are you using a bus? Can't you use regular Pinia/Vuex? Would solve quite some headache IMO.

Comment: I am using Vuex thoroughly, and just wanted to minimize the amount of Vuex watchers (and avoid having to scrutinize deep Vuex stores, reactivity and whether listeners would trigger inadvertently). A bus (any) is a nice fire-and-forget explicit send/receive, and here's the first time I have a problem with it (Nuxt's bus).

Comment: The app has a bus anyhow for UI things (nothing to do with Vuex).

Comment: Where are you triggering `myGlobalEvent`? Can you share a link to a reproduction of the problem?